# GPS returning Null Location in Some android devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

In my application i need to show Current Lcoation every 30 minutes.To implement this, I have used Timer to trigger every 30 minutes.

It's working fine in some android devices like HTC Wildfire S, Sony Xperia V...
but it's not working in Samsung S Duos and HTC One X...Because when i request GPS it returning NULL as Current Location value.I dont' know why that devices are not support my application can anyone help with profe.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for provider availability like this:

```
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
```

and then you start listening to available sensors:

```
if (providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,...);
}
```

If the sensors you want are not available you should popup a dialog to user to ask him to activate the GPS, or what you want.

Also, I have a recommendation to you: you should not start requesting location updates with `Timer`, you should pass to `requestLocationUpdates()` the minimum time & distance you want location updates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Actually provider is enabled but the GPS returning null Location some times. For that i used runOnFiristFix() thread also it works in first two devices but not in that Samsung s duos and HTC One X...